# Is it possible to write arbitrary depth delegated generators in Python?

Tags: python, yield-from

I would like to write a class with the following interface.

```
class Automaton:
    """ A simple automaton class """
    def iterate(self, something):
        """ yield something and expects some result in return """
        print("Yielding", something)
        result = yield something
        print("Got \"" + result + "\" in return")
        return result

    def start(self, somefunction):
        """ start the iteration process """
        yield from somefunction(self.iterate)
        raise StopIteration("I'm done!")


def first(iterate):
    while iterate("what do I do?") != "over":
        continue


def second(iterate):
    value = yield from iterate("what do I do?")
    while value != "over":
        value = yield from iterate("what do I do?")


# A simple driving process
automaton = Automaton()
#generator = automaton.start(first)    # This one hangs
generator = automaton.start(second)    # This one runs smoothly
next_yield = generator.__next__()
for step in range(4):
    next_yield = generator.send("Continue...({})".format(step))
try:
    end = generator.send("over")
except StopIteration as excp:
    print(excp)
```

The idea is that Automaton will regularly yield values to the caller which will in turn send results/commands back to the Automaton.

The catch is that the decision process "somefunction" will be some user defined function I have no control over. Which means that I can't really expect it to call the iterate method will a `yield from` in front. Worst, it could be that the user wants to plug some third-party function he has no control over inside this Automaton class. Meaning that the user might not be able to rewrite his `somefunction` for it to include `yield from` in front of `iterate` calls.

To be clear: I completely understand why using the `first` function hangs the automaton. I am just wondering if there is a way to alter the definition of `iterate` or `start` that would make the `first` function work.

Comment: What would it look like to make the `first` function "work"? It is not a generator, and `yield from` will always fail.  If your `start` function requires the argument to be a generator, you can add a check for that and raise a `TypeError` if the caller gives normal function like `first`

Comment: I think you many find [How do I form multiple pipelines with generators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924087/how-do-i-form-multiple-pipelines-with-generators) helpful.